# To get the size of image after requesting image asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I use EGOImage to request image asynchronously from the remote. But the Size of EGOImageView is assigned before requesting. The problem is that the image requested from remote has different size. So is possible to resize the imageView or some other solutions?

Thanks!

ps: the way to use EGOImage:

```
imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = oldFrame;
imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

Comment: Does EGOImageView has delegate method which fires when it would have loaded the image ? If it has then you can resize the imageview into that method

Comment: @Ankush thanks！ you should answer me below so I can accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achieve this you can use the delegate method `imageViewLoadedImage`. On successful loading of image your delegate method will be fired and in this method you can resize the imageView.

Answer (score 1):

Does EGOImageView has delegate method which fires when it would have loaded the image ? If it has then you can resize the imageview into that method.